# Port Forwarding In 450TC1 MTNL Router

Tags: router, port-forwarding

Does anyone have any idea how I can do port forwarding with my 450TC1 router and what are the proper steps to do it?

I need to get my WAMP server online so that other people can access it via the internet when I put my WAMP server online.

Moreover does **Port Forwarding** require a static IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Beetel 450TC1 refers to port forwarding as "Virtual Server", and it's under Advanced Setup > NAT > Virtual Server.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login in your router;
2. Advance Setup;
3. NAT;
4. DMZ Host.
5. In DMZ host Ip Address assign your Lan Ip address and Save and Reboot.

It will be Access by other People.

Yes it required a Static Ip from your ISP.